# "ThisWorkbook.Saved = True" not working on SharePoint with activeX button clicked

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, activex

I use `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` in Excel's "ThisWorkbook" object in order to suppress the "save changes" prompt:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)  
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True  
End Sub
```

I also have an ActiveX button that does a simple random task (like write a value into a cell, or pop up a msgbox, I tried different tasks, no difference).

That's all in my Excel file.

I found that `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` does not work if I had the Excel opened from a SharePoint site (select open in app) and clicked the button before I closed the file, "save changes" prompt still pops up. But if I work with the file from a local drive, then the code will work no matter what I do before closing the file.

To summarize:

```
from SharePoint,  button clicked                          --> "save changes" pops up.
from SharePoint,  random editing except for button click  --> "save changes" suppressed successfully.  
from Local Drive, no matter what I do                     --> "save changes" suppressed successfully.
```

I tried this on different SharePoint sites, the issue persists no matter whether the site has OneDrive sync enabled or not.

This happens only to ActiveX button. Form control button does not encounter this issue.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the user has the necessary permissions to save the workbook in the SharePoint library. If the user doesn't have sufficient permissions, they might not be able to save the workbook, even with VBA code.